# Make Zend\Db (zf2) between clause inclusive

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, between

I'm currently using Zend Framework 2 and a query with date ranges to obtain data out of a MySQL DB, and I came across the between clause that was previously not available in ZF1.

However, my code which looks something like this is not working correctly:

```
   $dateStart = '2012-12-20';
   $dateEnd = '2012-12-31';

   $sql = new Sql($_db);
   $select = $sql->select()
                ->from(array("t" => $table))
                ->columns(array("col1" => "col_as_1", "col2" => "col_as_2"));

 $select->where->between("date", $dateStart, $dateEnd);
 $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
 $result = $stmt->execute()->getResource()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Apparently the between clause is not inclusive, I can only get results until 2012-12-30, is there a way to make it inclusive? I've been taking a look at the ZF2 docs but they are not very helpful and running the same query on MySQL query browser returns all of the data I need.

Answer (score 2):

So you can try `lessThanOrEqualTo` and `greaterThanOrEqualTo`.

Between doesn't seem to provide this functionality: `between($identifier, $minValue, $maxValue)`

If you trace out your query with `$select->__toString()` you can see the query as string.

I don't have ZF2 on my computer but I could imagine that `between` in ZF2 will output `date > '2012-12-20' AND date < '2012-12-31'`.

Comment: Conceptually it is a valid answer (though maybe a bit too brief?). @redreggae - Can you elaborate more on how this will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE THIS : WHEN USING `between` on Mysql**

```
date_column_name between 'startDate' AND 'endDate'
```

**NOTE :** you should want to insert **+1 date** to **endDate** . Because of when you insert 2015-05-18 date to **endDate**.you can not get data of 2015-05-18.So you need to **plus one date** to **endDate**.

You can do it using this

```
$plusToDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate . ' + 1 day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The BETWEEN should be inclusive, are you sure there are no hours, minutes and seconds after the date, that would cause it not to select dates on 2012-12-31 since 2012-12-31 00:00:01 would technically be > 2012-12-31

Answer (score 0):

Format must be same, use mysql DATE function

`$select->where->between("DATE(date)", DATE('.$dateStart.'), DATE('.$dateEnd.'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($AppCleaner->from_date ));
$to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($AppCleaner->to_date ));

  $select->where->between('appointment_date', $from_date . ' 00:00:00', $to_date . ' 23:59:59');
```

also, Use the between clause as below:

```
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->from('app_posts');
        $select->where->NEST->between( 'id', 30,40);
        $select->group('app_posts.id');
 //     echo $select->getSqlString($this->adapter->getPlatform());
//      exit;
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $resultSet = new ResultSet();
        $resultSet->initialize($result);
        $posts = $resultSet->buffer()->toArray();
        return $resultSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//I have a static function to make conversion Data Format

```
public static function convertBrazilianDate2MySQLDatabase($dataBrazil) {
    $array = explode("/", $dataBrazil);
    $array = array_reverse($array);
    $str = implode($array, "/");

    return date("Y-m-d", strtotime($str));
}
```

//In My Service I built my sentence

```
    $dtStart = \Estrutura\Helpers\Data::convertBrazilianDate2MySQLDatabase($dt_start) . ' 00:00:01';
    $dtEnd = \Estrutura\Helpers\Data::convertBrazilianDate2MySQLDatabase($dt_end) . ' 23:59:59';
    $select->where->between('field name in table', $dtStart, $dtEnd);
```

[...]